# Radio button hover animation

Tags: css

I'm trying to have a round border around my radio button fade in upon hover. The issue I'm facing is the hover border is being painted on the inside of the button as well as the outside. I'd only like the border on the outside. Additionally, the fade in transition is not working. Some advice appreciated. Thank you.

```css
input[type='radio'] {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #747474;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

input[type='radio']:hover:before {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 12px rgba(80, 80, 200, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type='radio']:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 20% auto;    
  border-radius: 50%;
}
    
input[type='radio']:checked:before {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio">
```

Comment: Do you really want the radio button to be rather faint when it starts off? I would suggest having it look like a proper radio button, opacity 1, for ease of seeing it, it’s the before you want to fade in

Answer (score 2):

You can check this code snippet with some explanation

```css
input[type='radio'] {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #747474;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
  /*transition: 0.3s;*/
}

input[type='radio']:hover:before {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 12px rgba(80, 80, 200, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type='radio']:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 10%; /* Keeping margin only 10% */
  padding: 10%; /* Increase the inner area for pushing the border out of the circle */
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s; /* Move your transition to here */
}
    
input[type='radio']:checked:before {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio">
```

Comment: You're welcome!~ If you think it's useful, could you mark the answer done too? That would be really helping other people facing a similar problem :D @pldfs

Answer (score 0):

Transition in before

```css
input[type='radio'] {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #747474;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

input[type='radio']:hover:before {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 12px rgba(80, 80, 200, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type='radio']:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 20% auto;    
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
    
input[type='radio']:checked:before {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio">
```

Comment: Thank you. This animation still has the color appear within the radio button, which I'd like to avoid. It looks like someone posted a working solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

I find it a bit hacky solution,
it might help.

```
 input[type='radio'] {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border: 2px solid #747474;
            border-radius: 50%;
            outline: none;
            opacity: 0.6;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }
input[type='radio']:hover:before {
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 12px rgba(80, 80, 200, 0.2);
            border-radius: 50%;
            opacity: 1;
        }
input[type='radio']:before {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;  
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
input[type='radio']:checked:before {
            background: green;
        }
```

```
<input type="radio">
```

Comment: Thank you. The animation didn't show for me. But, it looks like another solution has been posted. If you'd like, you could post a code snippet so we can confirm it's not an issue on my side.

Answer (score 0):

added animation and also the hover border is now outside only

```css
 input[type='radio'] {
            /* add margin here of If you want */
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border: 2px solid #747474;
            border-radius: 50%;
            outline: none;
            opacity: 0.6;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }
input[type='radio']:hover:before {
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 12px rgba(80, 80, 200, 0.2); /* control thickens on border here */
            border-radius: 50%;
            opacity: 1;
        }
input[type='radio']:before {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            width: 100%; /* outside border*/
            height: 100%; /* for outside border */
            border-radius: 50%;
            transition:.3s; /* for animation*/
        }
input[type='radio']:checked:before {
            background: green;
        }
```

```html
<input type="radio">
```